# What's Shiva (Drug)?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, medicine-and-drugs

I only know that the shiva drug was used in the "Eurowar" but what's the effect of the drug?
And is it possible to get in Shadowrun 5 or is it impossible? Does it still exsist?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So far Shiva is not part of any supplement for Shadowrun 5.

But the german version of War! ("Fronteinsatz") for SR4 got - as usual - some bonus content. Not everything got into the final version. Some of those spare parts were released for free [here](https://sirdoomsbadcompany.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/shadowrun-exklusiv-die-shiva-option-fronteinsatz/). It's written in german. The statblock for Shiva reads as follows

**SHIVA**
**Duration:** 2 x 1d6 Hours
**Effect:** +2 constitution, +5 strength, -2 willpower, high pain tolerance 2, berserk, disorientation
**Disorientation:** The victim suffers a dice pool modicication of -2 on all actions because of confusion and disorientation for 10 minutes.

The next paragraph describes how this drug only causes nausea for a third of the users and the other two third gain full benfit but also suffer 20S damage without a resistance test (and hence die) as the drug wears of.

For 2074 the text states that officially there are no samples of this drug left but remnants might be found.

As SR4 and SR5 are very similar, you can use the given statblock.

Comment: +5 seems a bit hight though, since +4 is the usual max for attribute boosts. It should probably be changed to +4 and Physical Limit +X should be added (I suggest X = 4).

Comment: Also 20S doesn't imply death in sr5 (don't know if this was different is sr4); In fact you can barely kill a Gnome with that damage, if he's at full health...

Comment: It's probably worth checking the full text if you can read it... IIRC, some drugs downer effect is completely unresisted. You just eat it. If you're already wounded, as you're likely to be after using a combat drug, 20S can easily kill

Comment: You take these 20S without a restistance test. Combined with some other injuries it will most likely kill you. I edited the answer and added this info.

Comment: Also... Grrr! Damned German extra content! Grrr!

Comment: Well, all books for SR5 are 20€. If you can understand it, I strongly recommend them.

Answer (score 2):

Rules for Shiva have been published in the German equipment book *State of the Art ADL* as *Shiva(vintage)*.

According to the book large quantities of the drug were produced before deciding the drug was useless, so there are still remainders available (12F, 200 NY/€).

It's highly addictive (Rating 11, Threshold 4, Addiction type: both).

#### Stats

**Vector**:  Ingestion
**Speed:** Immediate
**Duration:** 2d6 Hours
**Effect:** \$\frac{1}{3}\$ chance of just causing *Nausea*; if it works +2 constitution, +2 strength, -2 willpower, high pain tolerance 4, berserk (like mentor spirit bear), *Disorientation*